# Openlayers: add Geocoder control to custom DIV

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

Geocoder is located in the MAP div. I would like to add this control into a custom div (with id "mapbar") outside the MAP div. 
How can I achieve that......

```
var geocoder = new Geocoder('nominatim', {
    provider: 'photon',
    lang: 'en-US',
    placeholder: 'Search for ...',
    limit: 5,
    debug: false,
    featureStyle: window["styleGeoLYRImage"]('red','#ff0026',5), // color filled circle
    autoComplete: true,
    keepOpen: false
});
```